# pymongo update same field value on large collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have more than **10 million documents** in my mongo collection. And image file extension `.jpg` is missing form field `variants.image_url` in approx **~6 million documents** and I want to update this field with missing extension `.jpg`.

I am running `find` query first to find all those documents and then `update` queries to update it, but this is very slow. how can I optimize this?

**Sample example:**

> { "variants" : [ { "image_url" : "http://assets.myassets.com/assets/images/2020/3/5/158642332113146/Arrow-ShirtsFossil-Smart-WatchesLee-Cooper-Formal-ShoesRoadster-Jeans" } ] }

will be changed to with `.jpg`

> { "variants" : [ { "image_url" : "http://assets.myassets.com/assets/images/2020/3/5/158642332113146/Arrow-ShirtsFossil-Smart-WatchesLee-Cooper-Formal-ShoesRoadster-Jeans.jpg" } ] }

```
# query through all where verion in not v2 and return only variants.image_url
 cursor = collection.find({"version": {"$ne": "v2"}}, {"variants.image_url": 1, "_id": 0})

 modified_count  = 0
 for record in cursor:
    modified_count = modified_count + update_image_url(record) 
 return modified_count


 def update_image_url(record)
    for key1 in record:
        # list
        for idx, elem in enumerate(record[key1]):
            # dict
            for key2 in elem:
                if str(elem[key2])[-4:] == ".jpg" or str(elem[key2])[-4:] == ".JPG":
                    print(".jpg or .JPG extension present. skipping")
                    return 0
                else:
                    query = {"variants.image_url": {"$eq": elem[key2]}}
                    new_value = {"$set": {"variants." + str(idx) + ".image_url": str(elem[key2]) + ".jpg"}}

                    update_result = collection.update(query, new_value)
                    print(update_result["nModified"], "nModified documents updated.")
                    return update_result["nModified"]
```

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.2.0

Comment: From version 4.2 onwards, you can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) that allows you to update documents while having reference to the current value, so you don't have to do separate find and update operations.

Comment: @thammada.ts let me try this. thanks !!!

Comment: You would have to use insensitive regex to find only documents that should be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by optimizing the second part i.e `update` query to **O(1)** time.  Instead of using a query on `variants.image_url`, I am using `_id` and since data is indexed on field `_id` this is taking O(1) time.

```
# return _id as well 
 cursor = collection.find({"version": {"$ne": "v2"}}, {"variants.image_url": 1})

 modified_count  = 0
 for record in cursor:
    modified_count = modified_count + update_image_url(record) 
 return modified_count


 def update_image_url(record)
    for key1 in record:
        # list
        for idx, elem in enumerate(record[key1]):
            # dict
            for key2 in elem:
                if str(elem[key2])[-4:] == ".jpg" or str(elem[key2])[-4:] == ".JPG":
                    print(".jpg or .JPG extension present. skipping")
                    return 0
                else:
                    # query on _id field O(1) time 
                    query = {"_id": {"$eq": record["_id"]}}
                    new_value = {"$set": {"variants." + str(idx) + ".image_url": str(elem[key2]) + ".jpg"}}

                    update_result = collection.update(query, new_value)
                    print(update_result["nModified"], "nModified documents updated.")
                    return update_result["nModified"]
```